# How to properly make Tkinter buttons in a for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

So I want to print an item's text when item's button is pressed.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('test')

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding='8')
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0)

items = [
    {
        'name' : '0001',
        'text' : '1111',
    },{
        'name' : '0002',
        'text' : '2222',
    },{
        'name' : '0003',
        'text' : '3333',
    },
]

rcount = 1 #row count
for item in items:
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=item['name']).grid(column=1, row=rcount, sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text='->', command=lambda:print(item['text'])).grid(column=2, row=rcount, sticky=W)
    rcount += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Whichever of the three buttons I press I get `3333`. If I remove lambda I get `1111 2222 3333` right at start of the program, but then buttons have no effect.

Comment: For example, I expected to see `3333 2222 1111 2222 3333` if I pressed buttons 3, 2, 1, 2, 3. Instead I get `3333 3333 3333 3333 3333` (in reply to the person asking what I expected the buttons to do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy change you can do is to use functools.partial instead of lambda. Since lambda evaluates the statement after the button is pressed, the last item would be 3333. partial saves the args and act the same as lambda(evaluate the statement after the button is pressed)

```
#rest the same
from functools import partial
for rcount, item in enumerate(items, start=1): #use this as row count
    ttk.Label(mainframe, text=item['name']).grid(column=1, row=rcount, sticky=W)
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text='->', command=partial(print,item['text'])).grid(column=2, row=rcount, sticky=W)
```

For more information on how to use partial see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: FWIW this problem can be solved with lambda, too. It's not the use of lambda that's wrong, it's the _incorrect_ use of lambda.

Comment: You're right that lambda could also be used to solve this problem, but I believe that it's easier to use partial instead